# GPG error on inexistent NO_PUBKEY id

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, gnupg, keyrings

I am facing a common issue on my ubuntu 22.04: can't execute `apt-get update` successfully because of missing signatures:

> Reading package lists... Done
> W: GPG error: https://dl.k6.io/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C780D0BDB1A69C86
> E: The repository 'https://dl.k6.io/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.

my issue is, the referenced key doesn't exist on my machine. the output of `apt-key list`:

```
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

pub   rsa4096 2021-03-12 [SC]
      C5AD 17C7 47E3 415A 3642  D57D 77C6 C491 D6AC 1D69
uid           [ unknown] k6.io (key for signing binaries) <security@k6.io>
sub   rsa4096 2021-03-12 [S] [expires: 2023-03-12]
sub   rsa4096 2021-03-12 [E]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa.gpg
------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-07-29 [SC]
      F23C 5A6C F475 9775 95C8  9F51 BA69 3236 6A75 5776
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for deadsnakes

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
------------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2015-10-28 [SC]
      BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF
uid           [ unknown] Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft-prod.gpg
-----------------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2015-10-28 [SC]
      BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF
uid           [ unknown] Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
      F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

I alredy tried execute: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C780D0BDB1A69C86` but, surprisely, it signed a different key and have no effect, the issue persists:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.4bZH9jxkOQ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C780D0BDB1A69C86
gpg: key 77C6C491D6AC1D69: "k6.io (key for signing binaries) <security@k6.io>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I just want to remove this error, i don't even have k6 installed on my machine anymore. Every source that i search ofixed the error by reproducing the above steps...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting the source list of k6 to fix the issue:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/k6.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/k6.list.save
```